# Render date option with Values.get

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

Cannot bind the query parameter for rendering the date using Google Sheets API v4 `Values.get`, it is giving the error:

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "DateTimeRenderOption":
>   Cannot bind query parameter.

What is the correct JSON payload?

```
var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("someSpreadsheetId", "Sheet1!A7", {"DateTimeRenderOption" : "SERIAL_NUMBER"});
```

PS = Quite strange that there is no code samples in Google Sheets API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `DateTimeRenderOption` to `dateTimeRenderOption`

The API Docs are a bit strange, especially when they [mix capitalization use](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.date_time_render_option).

Comment: thank you, it works fine. Indeed finding it difficult with the API Docs, there is not many code examples provided.